# Raspberry Pi to windows machine rdp audio problem?

Tags: audio

I am connecting to a Windows 7 machine, from my Raspberry Pi, and have earphones connected on the Raspberry Pi.

When I play a video on the Windows 7 machine, I cannot hear the audio.

How can I solve this?

Comment: What software are you using to connect to Windows from Raspberry Pi?

Comment: so, you connect FROM raspbery pi TO windows 7?

Comment: Has "Stese" reversed the intent of the question?

Answer (score 2):

> NOTE: since @stese has edited the question, it seems like the connection is the other way around compared to the original question

In remote desktop client on PC

Go to "Local Resources"

Click on Settings in "Remote Audio"

Select "Play on Remote Computer"

Profit

Comment: oh, wait ... I think I got the "connection" the other way around!!

Answer (score 0):

From Raspberry Pi to Windows 7 desktop, it will depend on the remote software you are using.  My preference is rdesktop.

To install rdesktop from command line:

```
sudo apt install rdesktop
```

To run rdesktop from command line:

```
rdesktop <my-computername>
```

To run rdesktop from command line with local sound (Pi sound):

```
rdesktop -r sound:local <my-computername>
```

rdesktop has a lot of other parameters that can change the look and feel of how rdesktop looks when executed, here is a cool way to set up a standard rdesktop command line (which can also be put in a `.sh` file and executed:

```
rdesktop -f -d <my-domain> -u <my-user-name> -p <my-auto-login-password> <my-computername>
```